# Multi threading is not working in order to upload files into S3

Tags: java, multithreading, amazon-s3

I have asked so many questions regarding this but still not able to tune my file upload to S3 .
Also i did not wanted to put every details in one question and make to very large to read others .

I have written my application in multi-threaded in order to upload files into 3 .
Somewhere my multi threading is not working and why i am saying is because when i printed the upload status i get below output

```
> Transfer: Uploading etc
>   - State: Waiting
>   - Progress: 0 Transfer: Uploading etc
>   - State: Waiting
>   - Progress: 0 Transfer: Uploading etc
>   - State: Waiting
>   - Progress: 0 Transfer: Uploading etc
>   - State: Waiting
>   - Progress: 0 Transfer: Uploading etc
>   - State: InProgress
>   - Progress: 0
```

I can see only one is in progress state rest of all thread is in waiting .
Is that my the indication that  my threading is not working correctly .

I suspect i am i am creating `TransferManager` out of `Runnable` and i am passing in constructor .

Here is my code .

This is my Executor

```
public class UploadExecutor {
    private static String fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\u6034690\\Desktop\\TWOFILE\\Samplefiles";
    // private static String fileLocation="D:\\TRFAudits_Moved\\";
    private static final String _logFileName = "s3FileUploader.log";
    private static Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(UploadExecutor.class);

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        _logger.info("----------Stating application's  main method----------------- ");
        AWSCredentials credential = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("TRFAuditability-Prod-ServiceUser").getCredentials();
        final ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("us-east-1")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credential)).withForceGlobalBucketAccessEnabled(true)
                .build();
        s3Client.getClientConfiguration().setMaxConnections(100);
        TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(s3Client);
        // while (true) {
        FileProcessThreads fp = new FileProcessThreads();
        List<File> records = fp.process(fileLocation);
        while (records.size() <= 0) {
            try {
                _logger.info("No records found willl wait for 10 Seconds");
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
                records = fp.process(fileLocation);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                _logger.error("InterruptedException: " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        _logger.info("Total no of Audit files = " + records.size());
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
        int recordsInEachThread = (int) (records.size() / 6);
        _logger.info("No of records in each thread = " + recordsInEachThread);
        UploadObject my1 = new UploadObject(records.subList(0, recordsInEachThread), tm);
        UploadObject my2 = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThread, recordsInEachThread * 2), tm);
        UploadObject my3 = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThread * 2, recordsInEachThread * 3), tm);
        UploadObject my4 = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThread * 3, recordsInEachThread * 4), tm);
        UploadObject my5 = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThread * 4, recordsInEachThread * 5), tm);
        UploadObject my6 = new UploadObject(records.subList(recordsInEachThread * 5, records.size()), tm);
        es.execute(my1);
        es.execute(my2);
        es.execute(my3);
        es.execute(my4);
        es.execute(my5);
        es.execute(my6);
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have made a simple s3 client class where I have s3 client instantiation and a upload method accepts file to be uploaded. in upload method I create new transfer manger every time it is invoked, while I share the s3 client in all invocations.

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha can you please share the details once please

Comment: I have used single file upload method not uploadFileList. Only change I can suggest, as you yourself have thought of, instantiate a new transfer manager for each upload oobject rather than passing same transfer manger.

Comment: @MadhavKumarJha i am facing `Timeout waiting for connection from pool` Can you please suggest .Also i am uploading very small file max 2 kb some time but frequency is very high ..

Comment: Not very sure .try shutting down the s3 client and transfer manger after use. Remember you should not shut down s3 client before you shut down all transfer manger.

Comment: also make sure you don't have concurrent threads running> the max connnections

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/269

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1405

Comment: @SUDARSHAN AWS has a threshold limit on the file size which is each file being uploaded must be a minimum of 5KB except the last part, maybe that is causing the issue internally